# How to create a type that either hold an `Array<Int>` or `UnsafePointer<UInt8>`

Tags: swift

I'm doing some performance testing of Swift vs Objective-C.

I created a Mac OS hybrid Swift/Objective-C project that creates large arrays of prime numbers using either Swift or Objective-C.

It's got a decent UI and shows the results in a clear display. You can check out the project on Github if you're interested. It's called [**SwiftPerformanceBenchmark**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/SwiftPerformanceBenchmark.git).

The Objective-C code uses a malloc'ed C array of ints, and the Swift code uses an `Array` object.

The Objective C code is therefore a lot faster.

I've read about creating an Array-like wrapper around a buffer of bytes using code like this:

```
let size = 10000
var ptr = UnsafePointer<Int>malloc(size)
var bytes = UnsafeBufferPointer<Int>(start: ptr, count: data.length)
```

I'd like to modify my sample program so I can switch between my `Array<Int>` storage and using an `UnsafeBufferPointer<Int>` at runtime with a checkbox in the UI.

Thus I need a base type for my `primes` array that will hold either an `Array<Int>` or an `UnsafeBufferPointer<Int>`. I'm still too weak on Swift syntax to figure out how to do this.

For my Array- based code, I'll have to use `array.append(value)`, and for the `UnsafeBufferPointer<Int>`, which is pre-filled with data, I'll use `array[index]`. I guess if I have to I could pre-populate my `Array` object with placeholder values so I could use `array[index]` syntax in both cases.

Can somebody give me a base type that can hold either an `Array<Int>` or an `UnsafeBufferPointer<Int>`, and the type-casts to allocate either type at runtime?

### EDIT:

Say, for example, I have the following:

```
let count = 1000

var swiftArray:[Int]?
let useSwiftArrays = checkbox.isChecked
typealias someType = //A type that lets me use either unsafeArray or swiftArray
var primesArray: someType?

if useSwiftArrays
{
  //Create a swift array version
  swiftArray [Int](count: count, repeatedValue: 0)
  primesArray = someType(swiftArray)
}
else
{
  var ptr = UnsafePointer<Int>malloc(count*sizeof(Int))
  var unsafeArray = UnsafeBufferPointer<Int>(start: ptr, count: data.length)
  primesArray =  someType(unsafeArray)
}

if let requiredPrimes = primesArray
{
  requiredPrimes[0] = 2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it’s not pretty but here is a generic function that will work on any kind of collection, which means you can pass in either an `Array`, or an `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer`, which means you can use it on a malloc’d memory range, or using the array’s `.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer`.

Unfortunately, some of the necessities of the generic version make it slightly less efficient than the non-generic version when used on an array.  But it does show quite a nice performance boost over arrays in `-O` when used with a buffer:

```
func storePrimes<C: MutableCollectionType where C.Generator.Element: IntegerType>(inout store: C) {
    if isEmpty(store) { return }
    var candidate: C.Generator.Element = 3
    var primeCount = store.startIndex
    store[primeCount++] = 2

    var isPrime: Bool
    while primeCount != store.endIndex {
        isPrime = true

        var oldPrimeCount = store.startIndex
        for oldPrime in store {
            if oldPrimeCount++ == primeCount { break }
            if candidate % oldPrime == 0 { isPrime = false; break }
            if candidate < oldPrime &* oldPrime { isPrime = true; break }
        }

        if isPrime { store[primeCount++] = candidate }

        candidate = candidate.advancedBy(2)
    }   
}

let totalCount = 2_000_000
var primes = Array<CInt>(count: totalCount, repeatedValue: 0)
let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

storePrimes(&primes)
// or…
primes.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { (inout buffer: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<CInt>) -> Void in
    storePrimes(&buffer)
}

let now = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
let totalTime = now - startTime
println("Total time: \(totalTime), per second: \(Double(totalCount)/totalTime)")
```

Answer (score 4):

@MartinR's suggestion should help get code that can switch between the two.  But there's a shortcut you can take to prove whether the performance difference is between Swift arrays and C arrays, and that's to switch the Swift compiler optimization to `-Ounchecked`.  Doing this eliminates the bounds checks on array indices etc that you would be doing manually by using unsafe pointers.

If I download your project from github and do that, I find that the Objective-C version is twice as fast as the Swift version.  But... that’s because `sizeof(int)` is 4, but `sizeof(Int)` is 8.  If you switch the C version to use 8-byte arithmetic as well...

[image: Swift wins]

p.s. it works the other way around as well, if I switch the Swift code to use `UInt32`, it runs at 2x the speed.

Comment: Martin's code uses a generic function that can take different kinds of objects. I want a pointer that can point to either type. I don't understand the syntax well enough to get that. That's what I'm looking for help with.

Comment: Wouldn't the -Ounchecked compiler setting turn off bounds checking for the entire app? That seems like serious overkill when what I want is to improve the speed on a single array.

Comment: Yeah I realize this isn't actually answering your question ;-) but thought I'd post it anyway.

Comment: That said, you aren't actually using subscripts or other bounds-checked stuff anywhere anyway (the `for...in`, for example, requires no checking and is just raw pointers under the hood) – just reran with `-O` (i.e. optimized but still bounds-checked) and Swift still beat the C version.

Comment: "Still" beat the C version? So you switched the optimization to "O" and the array type to UInt32, and Swift is faster? I'm testing against the release version, which has optimization set to "Fastest" and Swift (with Int type, or Int64) is about 3 times slower.

Comment: I'm running the beta (Xcode 6.3 beta 4/Swift 1.2), and there were some improvements to arrays in that.  [Here's](https://gist.github.com/airspeedswift/dffe6dd19a4bf6ef91b5) a couple of standalone non-UI versions and the sample I see on my machine, C version has a slight edge.

Comment: It is possible to change the behavior of just one collection object (e.g. turn off bounds checking for just my prime numbers array.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74377/discussion-between-duncan-c-and-airspeed-velocity).

Comment: @DuncanC posted a second answer with a generic version

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure if I understand your problem correctly, but perhaps
this goes into the direction that you need.

Both `Array` and `UnsafeMutablePointer` conform to `MutableCollectionType` (which requires a subscript getter and setter).
So this function would accept both types:

```
func foo<T : MutableCollectionType where T.Generator.Element == Int, T.Index == Int>(inout storage : T) {
    storage[0] = 1
    storage[1] = 2
}
```

Example with buffer pointer:

```
let size = 2
var ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>(malloc(UInt(size * sizeof(Int))))
var buffer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Int>(start: ptr, count: size)

foo(&buffer)
for elem in buffer {
    println(elem)
}
```

Example with array:

```
var array = [Int](count: 2, repeatedValue: 0)
foo(&array)
for elem in array {
    println(elem)
}
```

For non-mutating functions you can use `CollectionType`
instead of `MutableCollectionType`.

Comment: That's getting there. See my edits for an explanation of what I need to do.